# Dynamically update fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

When I create new sesid in session I need all the courses to add to the sesid in Registration model.

I am creating a result management system using django.
What I want to do is to

- create a session (it is done)
- then automatically, all the courses from course model will be in the
  session model ( I don't need to add individually) and then show a
  page that enables to add batch to the added courses.
- After submission all the students of the corresponding batch will be
  added to the course and thus session and redirect to somewhere to enable user to assign each course to a specific teacher
- each of the students have several marks fields to cover by the assigned teacher
- the result will be calculated and saved in the database after input from a table (better as an imported excel file)

so far, I have made this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Course(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cnam = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cidn = models.IntegerField()
    cred = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'IT-' + str(self.cidn) + ' - ' + self.cnam

class Student(models.Model):
    snam = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sroll = models.IntegerField()
    sreg = models.IntegerField()
    sbtc = models.IntegerField()
    sses = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.snam

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    umob = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    ulogo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def createprofile(selfsender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = Teacher.objects.creeate(user=kwargs['instance'])

class Session(models.Model):
    sesid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,verbose_name= ('Session'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sesid)
    def get_absolute_url(selfself):
        return reverse('Dashboard:session')

class Registration(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return str(self.session.sesid) + ' - ' + 'IT-' + self.str(course.cidn) + ' - ' + self.course.cnam + ' - ' + self.str(Teacher.user)

class Result(models.Model):
    reg = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ct1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ct2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ct3 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    asn = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    # avg
    atd = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    #total
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reg.session) + ' - ' + 'IT-' + str(self.reg.course.cidn) + ' - ' + self.student.snam
```

views.py:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from .tables import *
from .models import *


from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm



class Login(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'Dashboard/login.html'

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Course.objects.all()

def course(request):
    table = CourseTable(Course.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/course.html', {'table': table})

def teacher(request):
    table = TeacherTable(Teacher.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/teacher.html', {'table' : table})

def student(request):
    table = StudentTable(Student.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/student.html', {'table' : table})

def result(request):
    table = ResultTable(Result.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'Dashboard/result.html', {'table' : table})



class SessionView(CreateView,ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/createSession.html'
    model = Session
    fields = ['sesid']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Session.objects.all()
```

**How can I approach to the dynamic update of database?**

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic" here?

Comment: I dont need to add each course to the session, rather add all at a time automatically when I create the session

Comment: When I create new sesid in session I need all the courses to add to the sesid in Registration model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the explanation in the comment, something like this should do the trick.

For reusability, you could also move the `for course...` bit to a method on `Session`, such as `add_courses(self, teacher): ...`

```
class SessionView(CreateView, ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/createSession.html'
    model = Session
    queryset = Session.objects.all()
    fields = ['sesid']

    def form_valid(self, form):  # this will be the creation form
        instance = form.save()  # save the empty session
        for course in Course.objects.all():
            Registration.objects.create(
               session=instance,
               course=course,
               teacher=self.request.user.teacher,  # (Is this correct?)
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: It is only working for one course,I need to make data of all course for this! also if there is no course, it sends error that it has no object_list

Comment: Working, but problem still though I delete records from admin, it still display beneath the view!